# How is Google Analytics Measurement Protocol different?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, measurement-protocol

I was checking GA Measurement Protocol to send data to GA from backend.Which is working fine.Url i am using is:

```
 https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?tid=UA-XXXXXXX-1&v=1&cid=9350&dp=home&t=pageview
```

(Please replace UA-XXXXXXX-1 with your own tracking id.)

Now i have a website which is GA enabled using javascript way.I checked in Chrome inspect that it sends information to google through url:

```
https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/__utm.gif?utmwv=5.6.5dc&utms=4&utmn=1588741400&............
```

I can use this url too to send information to google from backend. What's special and new in Measurement Protocol because using this url too i can send data to google for analytics purposes?

I need to send data from backend to GA so please guide.

Comment: Try and figure out what all the parameters in the second url mean (measurement protocol is nicely documented).

Comment: @EikePierstorff : Is documentation the only reason?

Answer (score 3):

The measurement protocol is now the "backbone" for data collection for Universal Analytics for all versions (web, mobile etc). Unlike the gif-method it is well documented and it can be called from every device/programming language that can send http requests (it will still return a transparent gif, though).

The main reason for using the measurement protocol is that everything else is deprecated and Google has announced that support for older tracking methods will be dropped. It looks like your second example uses an older version of the Analytics tracking code, current versions send their calls to the `https://www.google-analytics.com/collect` endpoint. You should not invest a lot of effort in developing solutions based on deprecated technology, especially if it offers no advantages over the current versions.

Answer (score 0):

Google measurement protocol is very useful when implementing distributed solution of a service like restful APIs.
The client is not known by the server, each client world wide can call the rest API so no javascript code is possible to be injected at the client.

Measurement protocol enabled us to track which kind of devices are calling our API, how many requests per endpoint, etc...